# Not quite understanding touchesBegan and touchesEnded

Tags: ios, touch

I've looked at Apple's sample touches app, and it doesn't address my issue. In their sample app, when a touch event happens, it tries to keep the view(s) located where the touch event is happening. That makes the logic simple. They simply look for the views whose frames contain the touch location.

That doesn't work in my scenario. Here is my scenario.

There is a view containing a bunch of subviews. The idea is to allow the user to sort of fling one of the subviews in the direction they gesture. I want the `touchesBegan` event to find the view whose center is closest to the touch.

I then want the `touchesEnded` event to move that same view by a velocity that is determined by the beginning and ending events. The velocity will not necessarily be the same as the finger velocity, so I can't simply "attach" the view to the touch location as Apple has done in the sample app.

I thought of flagging the view identified in `touchesBegan` with the touch object, and using it to compare with the touch object in the `touchesEnded` event, but that's not working. The touch object is not the same for the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` events.

So what am I missing? How can I save the relationship between the view to be moved and the touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The touch object is, actually, the same in `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`. That turned out to be the way to track the touches.

Answer (score 0):

The TouchObject won't be similiar. The object will change with the touched view, location etc.
Please check the [UITouch Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the details.

**Suggestion 1:**

I implemented the same thing in my project by **subclassing the UIView** and adding the touch delegates inside the subclass.
And I created the instance of this subclass instead of normal UIView.

```
@interface myView : UIView
@end


@implementation myView

//over ride the following methods
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

@end
```

**Suggestion 2**

Use [UIPanGesture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for doing the same. It'll be a more easier way.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureMoveAround:)] autorelease];
[panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
[panGesture setDelegate:self];
[yourSubView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

-(void)panGestureMoveAround:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture;
{
    UIView *piece = [gesture view];
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:[piece superview]];
        [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y+translation.y*0.1)];
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
    }
}
```

An example is [here](http://blog.shoguniphicus.com/2011/06/15/working-with-uigesturerecognizers-uipangesturerecognizer-uipinchgesturerecognizer/)

Comment: Suggestion 1 is what I'm trying to do. The thing is, I don't know how many touches there will be at a time, and my views are moving around. So I need some way of determining for each touchEnded, what the closest view was to it at the time the touch began. Maybe I have to keep track of the whole motion instead of just the begin and end points. I think they can daisy chain by coordinates.

Comment: I started out using pan but discarded the idea because of the randomness of the touches. The app will be used by up to four simultaneous users each touching asynchronously with respect to each other. I don't think I can do that with pan.

Comment: @VictorEngel: I think you need to check the CGRectInsect in touches ended to find the nearest view. or intersected view. If you subclassed the UIView that was added as subView then the touces event method will occur for each and every subviews without issue. You don't want to worry about which view caused the touch event.

Comment: you seem to have a typo, but if I follow what you're saying, finding which view contains the touch at the touchesEnded event will usually get the wrong view unless I can refer to the location of the touchesBegan and the location of the view at the touchesBegan time. That means flagging the view during touchesBegan and acting on the flag in touchesEnded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. In this solution, `scaledView` is the view in which arrow views move. They are of class `spriteView`, which is a subclass of `UIView`.

```
-(spriteView *)findArrowContainingTouch:(UITouch *)touch inView:(UIView *)scaledView atPoint:(CGPoint) touchPoint
//There could be multiple subviews whose rectangles include the point. Find the one whose center is closest.
{
   spriteView * touchedView = nil;
   float bestDistance2 = 9999999999.9;
   float testDistance2 = 0;
   for (spriteView *arrow in scaledView.subviews) {
      if (arrow.tag == ARROWTAG) {
         if (CGRectContainsPoint(arrow.frame, touchPoint)) {
            testDistance2 = [self distance2Between:touchPoint and:arrow.center];
            if (testDistance2<bestDistance2) {
               bestDistance2 = testDistance2;
               touchedView = arrow;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return touchedView;
}
```

The method `distance2Between` computes the square of the distance between two points.

```
-(spriteView *)findArrowTouchedAtLocation:(CGPoint)p inView:(UIView *)scaledView
{
   spriteView * arrow = nil;
   for (spriteView *testArrow in scaledView.subviews) {
      if (testArrow.tag == ARROWTAG) {
         if ((p.x == testArrow.touch.x) && (p.y == testArrow.touch.y)) {
            arrow = testArrow;
         }
      }
   }
   return arrow;
}
```

There are subviews that are not arrows in the `scaledView`, so I use the constant ARROWTAG to identify the arrows.

```
#pragma mark - Touches
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UIView *scaledView = [self getScaledView];
   for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
      CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:scaledView];
      spriteView * arrow = [self findArrowContainingTouch:touch inView:scaledView atPoint:touchLocation];
      if (!(arrow==nil)) {
      //Record the original location of the touch event in a property, originalTouchLocation, of the arrow instance. Additionally, store the same point on the property touch.
      //Both properties are necessary. The originalTouchLocation will be used in `touchesEnded` and is not available in the `touch` object. So the information is stored separately.
      //The `touch` property, a CGPoint, is stored in order to identify the view. This property is updated by every touch event. The new value will be used by the upcoming event to find the appropriate view.
         arrow.touch = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
         arrow.originalTouchLocation = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
         arrow.debugFlag = YES;
         arrow.timeTouchBegan = touch.timestamp;
      }
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UIView *scaledView = [self getScaledView];
   for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
      CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:scaledView];
      CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:scaledView];
      //previousLocation is used to find the right view. This must be in the coordinate system of the same view used in `touchesBegan`.
      spriteView * arrow = [self findArrowTouchedAtLocation:previousLocation inView:scaledView];
      if (!(arrow==nil)) {
         arrow.touch = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
      }
   }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UIView *scaledView = [self getScaledView];
   for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
      CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:scaledView];
      CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:scaledView];
      spriteView * arrow = [self findArrowTouchedAtLocation:previousLocation inView:scaledView];
      if (!(arrow==nil)) {
         arrow.touch = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
         float strokeAngle = [self findAngleFrom:arrow.originalTouchLocation to:touchLocation];
         float strokeDistance2 = sqrt([self distance2Between:arrow.originalTouchLocation and:touchLocation]);
         NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = touch.timestamp - arrow.timeTouchBegan;
         float newArrowSpeed = strokeDistance2 / timeElapsed / 100; //might want to use a different conversion factor, but this one works quite well
         arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(strokeAngle);
         arrow.currentSpeed = newArrowSpeed;
      }
   }
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UIView *scaledView = [self getScaledView];
   for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
      CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:scaledView];
      spriteView * arrow = [self findArrowTouchedAtLocation:previousLocation inView:scaledView];
      if (!(arrow==nil)) {
         arrow.originalTouchLocation = CGPointMake(99999.0, 99999.0);
         NSLog(@"Arrow original location erased");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to scrap this answer, because it doesn't work. I've found that sometimes the locationInView and previousLocationInView in touchesEnded match the last value found in touchesMoved. Other times, the last entry for locationInView in touchesMoved matches the previousLocationInView in touchesEnded, as is assumed in this code. I switched back to the original idea of tracking the touch object itself, and I got it to work. I'll probably wind up deleting this entire question, unless someone objects, since its premise was wrong.